# How to force observables to execute in sequence?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I am moving from the Promise world to the Observable world. One thing I usually do with Promise is to chain a series of tasks and make them run in sequence. For example, I have three tasks: `printLog1()` to print 1 to the console, `printLog23()` to print 2 and 3 to the console, and `printLog4()` to print 4.

When I want to print 1-2-3-4, I would write a promise chain like

```js
printLog1()
  .then(() => {
    printLog23();
  })
  .then(() => {
    printLog4();
  });
```

Now I want the same functionality with Observable and I can rewrite the `printLog()` function into an Observable like

```js
printLog1 = Rx.Observabale.of(1).map((i) => console.log(i));
printLog23 = Rx.Observabale.of(2, 3).map((i) => console.log(i));
printLog4 = Rx.Observabale.of(4).map((i) => console.log(i));
```

Then I have three observables that emits different values to the console. How do I chain them so that these three observables would run in order and print `1-2-3-4`?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you want to be sure the order of emissions is the same as the order in which you specified the source Observables you can use `concat` or `concatMap` operators.

The `concat*` operators subscribe to an Observable only after the previous Observable completes (it works with Promises as well, see [http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObservableInputDoc.html](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js%7EObservableInputDoc.html)).

In you case it'd look like the following:

```js
import { concat } from 'rxjs'; // Note, concat from 'rxjs', is not the same as concat from 'rxjs/operators'

concat(printLog1, printLog23, printLog4);
```

... or with `concatMap` if the request for one Promise depends on the response from the previous Promise:

```js
printLog1.pipe(
  concatMap(response => ...),
  concatMap(response => ...),
);
```

... or when the order doesn't matter you can use `merge` that subscribes to all Observables/Promises immediately and reemits their results as they arrive:

```js
merge(printLog1, printLog23, printLog4);
```

Jan 2019: Updated for RxJS 6

Comment: I tested this method along lines of `const $printLog1 = from(someFunc1Async())` and  `const $printLog2 = from(someFunc2Async())` and then tried to use concat unsuccessfully.  The assignment above with `from` cause invocation immediately..  Maybe obvious but hopefully helps someone else.

Comment: Hey there!
Thanks! I did `merge` on 2 observables and I got both responses, but I don't know which one is for which one. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```js
const sequence: Observable<any>[] = [of(1), of(2), of(3)];

return concat(...sequence).pipe(toArray());
```