# How to call dependent HTTP services in Angular 2 \ 4?

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, observable

I have a situation where I need to call 4 services with dependency on previous service result.

For instance, there are 4 tabs\buttons named 'Level 1', 'Level 2', 'Level 3' and 'Level 4'.

On load of screen, I need to call just 'Level 1' service:
`this.levelService.getLevel1()` //returns observable and bind the result of this to a array variable `level1Arr` (this will be a check box list, in which 10 items will be checked by default).

Next, when user clicks on 'Level 4', I need to pass those 10 `level1Arr` item ids(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) as input to 2nd service  `this.levelService.getLevel2()`, which again returns a result back and will be stored in `level2Arr`. Now I need to call  `this.levelService.getLevel3()` by passing 2 parameters (from `leve1Arr` and `level2Arr`). Similarly `this.levelService.getLevel4()` (with 3 parameters this time) will be called.

This can be done by calling subsequent services within the result of previous service. However, the number of levels will be dynamic and may vary. Hence I wanted to know if there is any better way in Angular \ Observable to handle such case.

Comment: I think you're looking for the `concat` operators. See [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43338150/1447173)

Comment: did you check on fork join or flatmap

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I'll try that option and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force observables to execute in sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336549/how-to-force-observables-to-execute-in-sequence)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to chain Http calls in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104638/how-to-chain-http-calls-in-angular2)