# Chain multiple calls with foreach loop and Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I want to chain multiple request to the urls which I get from the array. Before next chain i want to wait for the previous one to finish. It's does not matter if the previous fails or not. I was trying to this with forkJoin but I know that if one of the request fails it will return error.

```
this.dataServers.forEach(dataServer => {
    observableBatch.push(this.getFoodsByQuery(dataServer.url, query));
});

return Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch).subscribe(data => {
    this.searchingServer.next(null);
    observer.complete();
});
```

I do not know how to do this with flatMap.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force observables to execute in sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336549/how-to-force-observables-to-execute-in-sequence)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case suitable operator is [**concat**](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-concat)

> Concatenates multiple Observables together by sequentially emitting
>   their values, one Observable after the other.

Example:

```js
// Batch of requests
let batch = [
  Observable.of(1),
  Observable.of(2).delay(1500),
  Observable.throw('Error'),
  Observable.of(3).delay(300),
  Observable.throw('Error again'),
  Observable.of(4).delay(600)
];

// Catch (ignore) error of every request
batch = batch.map(obs => {
  return obs.catch(err => Observable.of(err));
});

// Concat observables 
Observable.concat(...batch).subscribe({
  next: v => console.log(v),
  complete: () => console.log('Complete')
});
```

Output:

```js
1
2
'Error'
3
'Error again'
4
'Complete'
```

Comment: It looks great I have edited my question code and in this situation i have to subscribe to v and my problem is fact that complete is resolve before I subscribe to all next.

Comment: I have another problem because i can not subscribe to v element but I need that

`Observable.concat(...observableBatch).subscribe({
        next: v => {
          v.subscribe(data => {
            this.searchingServer.next(this.dataServers[index]);
            index ++;
            observer.next(data);
            if(index == this.dataServers.length){
              observer.complete();
              this.searchingServer.next(null);
            }
          })
        },
        complete: () => console.log("complete")
      });`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using OnErrorResumeNext() with forkJoin?

```
return Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch)
.OnErrorResumeNext()
.subscribe(data => {
  this.searchingServer.next(null);
  observer.complete();
});
```

Comment: But this calls are done one by one as it is with flatMap?