# How to do sequence maps so that each map waits for the previous in rxjs?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

```
const source = Rx.Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
const example = source.map(val => { /* asynchronous logic here*/ })
                      .map(val => { /* asynchronous logic here*/ });
                      .map(val => { /* asynchronous logic here*/ });
```

How to make so that each `map` waits for the asynchrounous execution of the previous `map`  ?

Comment: did you take a look at flatmap i think that is what you need [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx/rxjs)

Comment: use `concatMap` and return an Observable from its callback.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336549/how-to-force-observables-to-execute-in-sequence/43338150#43338150

Comment: @martin you are my hero, Please write an answer so that I accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `concatMap` instead of `map` and return Observable from its callback:

```
const source = Rx.Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
const example = source
  .concatMap(val => { /* asynchronous logic here*/ })
  .concatMap(val => { /* asynchronous logic here*/ })
  .concatMap(val => { /* asynchronous logic here*/ });
```