# Why does this little rxjs-code-snippet using the concat-operator throw an error?

Tags: rxjs

**Preconditions:**
The ref.getDownload() returns an Observable which only can be subscribed, if the
task.snapshotChanges()-Observable completed.

**This code-snippet works:**

```
task.snapshotChanges().subscribe({
  complete: () => {
    ref.getDownloadURL().subscribe((downloadUrl) => console.log(downloadUrl));
  }
});
```

**This code-snippet does NOT work:**

```
concat(
  task.snapshotChanges(),
  ref.getDownloadURL()
).pipe(
  last()
).subscribe((downloadUrl) => console.log(downloadUrl));
```

getDownloadUrl throws an error (404 file not found), because it seems
ref.getDownloadUrl is subscribed to early.

Why subscribes the ref.getDownloaded()-Observable and does not wait until task.snapshotChanges() completes? The concat-operator should ensure this behaviour.
Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `ref.getDownloadURL()` is called when the `concat(..)` Observable is created. See:

```js
const { of, concat } = rxjs; 
const { delay } = rxjs.operators;

const fetch1 = () => { console.log('run fetch1'); return of('from 1').pipe(delay(2000)) }
const fetch2 = () => { console.log('run fetch2'); return of('from 2').pipe(delay(2000)) }

concat(fetch1(), fetch2()).subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

`ref.getDownloadURL()` seems to query the database directly when it gets called and not when the Observable it returns gets subscribed to.

You can wrap `ref.getDownloadURL()` with `defer` to only execute it when the Observable is subscribed to.

```js
const { of, concat, defer } = rxjs; 
const { delay } = rxjs.operators;

const fetch1 = () => { console.log('run fetch1'); return of('from 1').pipe(delay(2000)) }
const fetch2 = () => { console.log('run fetch2'); return of('from 2').pipe(delay(2000)) }

concat(fetch1(), defer(() => fetch2())).subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Also see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57671521/9423231