# Typescript execute function after two subscriptions return

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two subscriptions to services. I need to run code after both of these subscriptions return all records. How do I accomplish this?

Here is the relevant current code current in ngOnit

```
this.userService.get$(this.userId).subscribe(
  u => this.user = u);

  this.roleService.getAll$().subscribe(
    r => this.roles = r);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force observables to execute in sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336549/how-to-force-observables-to-execute-in-sequence)

Comment: If they don't have to be executed in sequence and you only care about the last emitted value take a look at RxJs forkJoin Operator: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin

 Otherwise concatMap should be a good fit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `forkJoin` for that - this will execute both request in parallel

```
forkJoin({
user:this.userService.get$(this.userId),
roles:this.roleService.getAll$()
}).subscribe(results=>{
    this.user=results.user;
    this.roles=results.roles;
    //do whetever has to be done here since both are complete
})
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get this working with only a minimum amount of work. I chose your answer because it allowed me to execute in parallel and the code was usable with very little changes

    forkJoin({
      user: this.userService.get$(this.userId ?? ''),
      roles: this.roleService.getAll$()
    }).subscribe(results => {
      this.user = results.user;
      this.roles = results.roles;
      console.log('work goes here');
    })

Comment: Im glad I could help. I have also removed reduntdant `subscribe` from he example as obviously it should not be there

Answer (score 1):

You have to use concat from rxjs to execute your Observable in sequence.

```
import { concat } from 'rxjs';    
concat(
    this.userService.get$(this.userId);
    this.roleService.getAll$();
    )
.subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: I see that you have did the same copy paste mistake like I did, inner `subscribe` should be removed.

Comment: Oh, you right. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use promise for this task, to see documentation [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
var first = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.userService.get$(this.userId).subscribe(u => {
        this.user = u
        resolve(u)
    });
});

var second = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.roleService.getAll$().subscribe(r => {
            this.roles = r
            resolve(r)
        });
});

Promise.all([first, second]).then((values) => {
    console.log(values);
});
```